# How to convert string into list string on specific expression in Dart?

Tags: dart

i have string who is

```
String hello = "test test {Brian} have you {Adam} always and {Corner} always";
```

want to make list string who is taking who have {string}
output :

```
List<String> data = ["{Brian}","{Adam}","{Corner}"];
```

its that possible in dart ?

i dont know what to use

Comment: You'd use a regex with the allMatches method against the string, and that will return a list of matches from which you can extract the string parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `RegExp(r"\{[^{}]*\}")`

```dart
String hello = "test test {Brian} have you {Adam} always and {Corner} always";
RegExp regExp = RegExp(r"\{[^{}]*\}");
    
print(regExp.allMatches(hello).map((e) => e[0]).toList());
```

---